# the problem of crypting data by C# on the server side and encrypting it by CryptoJS on the client side

Tags: c#, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I got stuck also a bit lost in C# and CryptoJS differences.i have two server side
functions to encrypt data by AES256 bit as follows;

```
public string EncryptText_PBKDF2(string input, string password)
    {           
        // Get the bytes of the strings         
        byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
        byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
        // Hash the password with SHA256 for AES key
        passwordBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(passwordBytes);
        byte[] bytesEncrypted = AES_Encrypt_PBKDF2(bytesToBeEncrypted, passwordBytes);
        string result = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesEncrypted);
        return result;
    }

private byte[] AES_Encrypt_PBKDF2(byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted, byte[] passwordBytes)
    {
        byte[] encryptedBytes = null;
        
        byte[] saltBytes = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            aes.KeySize = 256;
            aes.BlockSize = 128;
            aes.IV = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(passwordBytes);//16 byte
            
            var PBKDF2_key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
            aes.Key = PBKDF2_key.GetBytes(aes.KeySize / 8);//32 byte
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(bytesToBeEncrypted, 0, bytesToBeEncrypted.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            encryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
        }
        return encryptedBytes;
    }
```

then i send it to view by a controller action;

```
string res = aesIsl.EncryptText_PBKDF2("my text", "my key");
ViewBag.Crypted1 = res;
```

on the client side i get it from a hidden field

```
<div id="crypted"><input id="hidden1" data-enc="@ViewBag.Crypted1" type="hidden" /></div>
```

and decrypt it by crypto-js library(i have 4 attempts indicated on top of them)

here is my decrypting function and attempts:

```
function AesleDesifrele_PBKDF2(ciphertext, pwd) {    
    var salt = "0000000000000000";
    var iv = CryptoJS.MD5(CryptoJS.SHA256(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(pwd)));          
    //these are my attempts to decrypt
    //ATTEMPT #1:
    //returning object contains a word array but converting it to utf8 string
    //causes "Malformed UTF-8 data" error
    console.log(CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext, pwd).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
    //ATTEMPT #2
    var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(
        CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(pwd).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8),
        CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(salt),
        { keySize: 128 / 32, iterations: 1000 }
    );
    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
        ciphertext,
        key,
        { iv: iv }
    );
    //returning object contains a word array but converting it to utf8 string
    //causes "Malformed UTF-8 data" error
    console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
    //ATTEMPT #3
    var raw = base64UrlDecode(ciphertext);
    var iv1 = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(CryptoJS.MD5(CryptoJS.SHA256(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(pwd))));;
    var salt1 = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(salt));
    var key1 = generateKey(pwd, salt1);
    var ciphertextWords = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(raw.words.slice(128 / 32 + 128 / 32));
    var cipherParams = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({ ciphertext: ciphertextWords });
    var plaintextArray = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
        cipherParams,
        key1,
        { iv: iv1 }
    );
    console.log(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(plaintextArray)); 
    //returning object contains a word array but converting it to utf8 string
    //returns nothing
    //ATTEMPT #4
    var iv2 = CryptoJS.MD5(CryptoJS.SHA256(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(pwd)));
    var Pass = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(pwd);
    var Salt = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(salt);
    var key256Bits1000Iterations = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(Pass.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8), Salt, { keySize: 256 / 32, iterations: 1000 });
    var cipherParams = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({
        ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(ciphertext)
    });
    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cipherParams, key256Bits1000Iterations, { mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, iv: iv2, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7 });
    console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
    //returning object contains a word array but converting it to utf8 string
    //returns nothing
}
```

this is the function to generate key for CryptoJs decrypt

```
function generateKey(secret, salt) {
return CryptoJS.PBKDF2(
    secret,
    salt,
    {
        keySize: this.keySize / 32, // size in Words
        iterations: 1000,
        hasher: CryptoJS.algo.SHA256
    }
);
```

}

this is the conversion function i use

```
function base64UrlDecode(str) {
    return CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(str.replace(/\-/g, '+').replace(/\_/g, '/'));
}
```

even though i control params on the client(cyphertext,password,IV and the salt) are exactly the same with the server,CryptoJS.decrypt returns nothing without any error.i guess i miss converting something to another in order C# to be compatible with CryptoJs.

any advice welcomes.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless you have a specific demand to use these algorithms in this particular way and no others, I'd recommend libsodium -- it has both C# and JS bindings and a much simpler interface.

Comment: This looks way too much like a random attempt to me. The first thing that sticks out is that you only seem to pre-hash the password (not just the IV) in C# using SHA-256. However, I would second Jeroen's comment (Hoi Jeroen) that inventing your own scheme would be a very bad idea, because I would completely break it in seconds flat, even though you use AES. By the way, the way to debug crypto code is to print out all intermediate values (key's IV etc.) in hexadecimals, and then look for the differences between the applications. Your code on both sides should be SYMMETRICAL just like the cipher

Comment: thanks Jeroen.i'll check it.also thank you Maarten for your comment.as you noticed i hashed pwd in C# using sha-256 to prepare it for AES256 usage.also i hash this hashed pwd in c# using md5 because  i use the same pwd(shared with diffie-hellman key exchange) and i hash it using md5 to use it as IV in JS side.i logged both sides values via hashing them.all values are the same.i think i have to do some conversion for crypto-js library,but i couldn't find which one to another and how to.thank you very much for your time.